# Using multiline regular expressions

Tags: regex

I need to separate individual records from:

```
Marriage of MARY ROCHE
in 1880
Group Registration ID   N/R
SR District/Reg Area    Cork
Returns Year    1880
Returns Quarter 4
Returns Volume No   5
Returns Page No 0110
Marriage of MARY ROCHE
in 1880
Group Registration ID   N/R
SR District/Reg Area    Enniscorthy
Returns Year    1880
Returns Quarter 3
Returns Volume No   4
Returns Page No 276
Marriage of MARY ROCHE
in 1880
Group Registration ID   N/R
SR District/Reg Area    New Ross
Returns Year    1880
Returns Quarter 3
Returns Volume No   4
Returns Page No 349
Marriage of MARY ROCHE
in 1880
Group Registration ID   N/R
SR District/Reg Area    Wexford
Returns Year    1880
Returns Quarter 3
Returns Volume No   4
Returns Page No 389
Marriage of MARY ROCHE
in 1880
Group Registration ID   N/R
SR District/Reg Area    New Ross
Returns Year    1880
Returns Quarter 3
Returns Volume No   4
Returns Page No 343
```

For instance the first record would be from Marriage (1st line) till 0110 (8th line).

How would you do that using regular expression in order to get a list with all the records?

thanks in advance

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: Python (ie library re)

Comment: You can put `\n` in a regular expression and it will match the line break. You can use `flags=re.DOTALL` to allow `.*` to match across lines.

Comment: thanks for your response,

but how would I differentiate this '\n' for every eight lines?

Since what I need is a list of strings containing this pattern.

Comment: I found this solution, but I wondered if there was a more beautiful version

'paragraphs = re.finditer('.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', brides, flags =  re.MULTILINE)'

Comment: Actually this solution provided is not suitable since the .txt file changes its structure alongside the file (i.e. there are empty lines within it...)

Comment: You can split on the zero-width matches of the regular expression `(?<!\A)(?=^Marriage of)`. The negative lookbehind prevents a match before 'Marriage of..' at the beginning of the string. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlgTcm/1)

Comment: appreciate ur help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below regular expression:

```
(Marriage).*?(?=Marriage|\Z)
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/x2HPMK/1

Comment: There is no need for the capture group and you might require 'Marriage' to be at the beginning of a line and followed by a space: `^Marriage .*?(?=Marriage|\Z)`.

Comment: Yeah, we can remove grouping at beginning of line.

Comment: You may wish to edit. Consider also the beginning-of-line anchor.

Comment: Also you don't mention the flags, which are important for it to work multiline

Comment: appreciate your help!

Comment: Daniel, I added that already in demo pls checkout demo link

Comment: Ive seen that already, thanks!